# How to upload a image to the server using intel xdk software and cordova

Tags: cordova

My Question: How to upload image on server using intel xdk software and cordova plugin.

Below Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function getImage() {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('get picture failed');
 }, {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 console.log(options.fileName);
 var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log(imageURI);
     alert(imageURI);
 ft.upload(imageURI, "http://servername/upload.php", function(result){

 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
 }, function(error){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }, options);
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getImage()">Upload a Photo</button>
</body>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
//Allow Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//print_r(json_encode($_FILES));

$new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

MY Question: I upload image on my android phone, but image can not upload to server. so please help me